# Connect Load data from APIs (data in form of JSON) and store in table

Tags: json, export-to-csv

I need to connect and fetch data from API (data will be in JSON form) and then store the data in form of table. I have extracted the data in JSON form using python but now when I am converting it in .csv form, then I m getting the error as **: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.**

The code I have used is as:

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv
f = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KORD:9:US/observations/historical.json?units=e&startDate=20140703&endDate=20140704&apiKey=742a31ced27a477045')
json_string = f.read()
x = json.loads(json_string)
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))

# For CSV Headers
f.writerow(["obs_id", "obs_name", "temp", "valid_time_gmt"])
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["observations"]["obs_id"],
                x["observations"]["obs_name"],
                x["observations"]["temp"],
               x["observations"]["valid_time_gmt"]])

f.close()
```

where extracted JSON  is like

```
> {   "metadata": {
>     "language": "en-US",
>     "transaction_id": "1484310885350:-90975020",
>     "version": "1",
>     "location_id": "KORD:9:US",
>     "units": "e",
>     "expire_time_gmt": 1484314485,
>     "status_code": 200   },   "observations": [
>     {
>       "key": "KORD",
>       "obs_id": "KORD",
>       "obs_name": "Chicago/O'Hare",
>       "valid_time_gmt": 1404453060,
>       "day_ind": "N",
>       "temp": 61
>     },
>     {
>       "key": "KORD",
>       "obs_id": "KORD",
>       "obs_name": "Chicago/O'Hare",
>       "valid_time_gmt": 1404456660,
>       "day_ind": "N",
>       "temp": 60
>     },....... and so on
```

Could you please help what needs to be changed here ?

Comment: The question is to broad. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Hi, python would be the most preferred one.But I am open to possibilities and best option available.

Comment: @MarcinRaczkowski Do these updates in question help ?